# supply custom view for setContentView not working?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view extending RelativeLayout (could be any other viewgroup). In this view I have several framelayouts added with addView(). No XML exists for this view! The view constructer adds everything from code.
I want to use this custom view as any other content view for an activity.
I have this fragment activity:
MyView myview;

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       myview = new MyView(this);
       myview.getSomeContainedFrameLayoutOfView().setId(12345);
       setContentView(myview);
   }
```

Then I do this in onResume

```
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {

  super.onResume();

  View u = findViewById(12345); // test, returns null
  u = myview.findViewById(12345); // test, also null
  SomeFragment f = new SomeFragment();
  FragmentManager m = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = m.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(12345, f); // ofcourse error (no view found for id)
  ft.commit();
  }
```

Why is `findViewById` null? If I change `setContentView()` line to
`setContentView(R.layout.myframelayouts);`
Everything works. So somehow I suspect
`setId(12345)`
does something different from:
`android:id="@+id/someid"`
What am I missing?

Comment: I think the XML is compiled into code in the app, and the code is run at runtime.  You seem to be missing the compilation bit.

Comment: if you're going to try and do this I'd recommend creating an [Id Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id) and using that as the id will be created for you at compile time then you just pass around an ID name rather then a number.

Answer (score 0):

Is the view returned by getSomeContainedFrameLayoutOfView() actually contained in the RelativeLayout?   That is, somewhere in MyView have you called AddView(theTargetView)?

If the target view is simply a member of MyView, then the RelativeLayout, which implements findViewById unless you override it, doesn't know about the target view.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```
public class MojLayout extends LinearLayout {

private FrameLayout lijeviFrame;
private FrameLayout glavniFrame;
private int layoutWidth;
private int panel;
private boolean glavniFrameFullScreen = false;

public MojLayout(final Context context, final float leftWeight) {
    super(context);

    lijeviFrame = new FrameLayout(context);
    glavniFrame = new FrameLayout(context);

    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            layoutWidth = getWidth();
            panel = (int) (layoutWidth / leftWeight);
            init(context);
        }
    });
}

private void init(Context context) {
    lijeviFrame.setId(R.id.lijeviFrame); //defined in /res/values/ids.xml
    glavniFrame.setId(R.id.glavniFrame);

    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(context);
    container.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
    ....
    container.addView(lijeviFrame);
    container.addView(glavniFrame);

    addView(container);
}
```

In onCreate() method I tried myView.findViewbyId(R.id.lijeviFrame) -> null, without myView, same.
I don't get it

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  However this isn't the same question.  In this code the constructor for your MojLayout posts a request for Init to be called back and init actually adds the child views.   That request will run on the UI thread, but onCreate is already running on that thread so Init will not be called until after onCreate returns.

Comment: You are right! I set the onGlobalLayoutListener and in this listener I was able to retrieve child IDs